# curl https://github.com fails with 443

Tags: git, macos, ssl, curl, github

I cannot connect to Github in MacOS Mojave 10.14.4, error: 443

`ping github.com` is working. Yes, the network is okay.

```
$ ping github.com
PING github.com (192.30.253.112): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.30.253.112: icmp_seq=0 ttl=49 time=443.705 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.253.112: icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=464.529 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.253.112: icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=382.513 ms
^C
--- github.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 382.513/430.249/464.529/34.809 ms
```

`curl -v https://github.com` fails with net error code 443.

```
$ curl -v https://github.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://github.com/
*   Trying 192.30.253.112...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to github.com (192.30.253.112) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443 
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443
```

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0) libcurl/7.54.0 LibreSSL/2.6.5 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.24.1
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

And I also can not use `git clone` command to clone code from github.com with same error 443. But I could browse the web github.com through a browser.

Comment: 443 is not an error, it's the TCP port number (and is standard for https connections). The error number from curl is 35, which is an SSL/TLS handshake failure.

Comment: I steal do not know how to solve it . can you tell me how?

Comment: `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` indicates error in TCP layer. So issue can be present outside of your machine. Sadly `curl` is unable to print details of this system error so it will be hard to help you. You can try with different ISP.